# Calling Cells.End in Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to get the last Row in Column `A`.
Does anyone know why the following does not compile?

It seem that it doesn't like `.End`…

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet; 
xlWorkSheet = 
    (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

int iLastRow = xlWorkSheet.Cells[1,"A"]
    .End(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDirection.xlUp)
    .Row;
```

Comment: compiles on my machine with version 14.0.0.0

Comment: I suggest you put `using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;` at the top of your code file; this way you could say `Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet = ...` and use `Excel.XlDirection.xlUp`.

Comment: Any error message you're getting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It compiles for me, your method always returns 1, I did this and it worked:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = xlApp.Worksheets[1];
var iLastRow = xlWorkSheet.Range["A1","A65000"].get_End(XlDirection.xlDown).Row;
```

To find the last used row I think this method is better:

```
var usedRows = xlApp.WorksheetFunction.CountA(xlWorkSheet.Columns[1]);
```

Comment: how do this in epplus?

Comment: @Ivan if you have a question click the "Ask Question" button.\