# Get Last non Empty Cell of Excel Column Programatically

Tags: c#, excel

I have excel sheets that always look like below

```
A |  B  |  C
  |     |    
  |     |  something here maybe 
1 |  x  |  k
2 |  y  |  l
3 |  z  |  n
  |  j  |  
  |  j  |  
   ...
  |     |
```

I want to get the value of the last non empty cell in A column. A column always starts at A6 and goes for a while and after than it is empty but column B continues for a while. This has the effect that if I use the code below:

```
sh = app.Workbooks.get_Item("Workbook1.xlsx").Worksheets.get_Item("Sheet1");
fullRow = sh.Rows.Count;
lastRow = sh.Cells[fullRow, 1].End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;
```

I get as last row the last row that has B non empty. Which might be even 50 rows below the place where A starts being null. Is there a way to do it with C# without iterating over all values?

**EDIT**

It turns out that Column A is based on column C so I should check for C. As it turns out C is yielding the same result with A maybe because of the function. Luckily there is a column D that does not have the same issue so if I use the code above changing 1 for 4 it works likes a charm.

Comment: Is sh.Cells zero-based, i.e., can you do `sh.Cells[fullRow, 0]`? I don't think so, but worth checking.

Comment: your code is ok for what you need. The only possibility I could think of, which gives you this result, is if you have any formulas in 'empty' cells in column A. These could be formulas which return empty string, like `=""`.

Comment: @DougGlancy I have already tired that and it throws an exception.

Comment: @KazJaw I will check for it but I a pretty sure it does have any formulas.

Comment: @idipous, in other words, try to check it manually in your excel file, with `ctrl+arrows`, where movement will stop. then analyse the content of cells.

Comment: @KazJaw you are right! Indeed the excel has a function e.g. `=IF(ISBLANK(C904);"";ROW(B904)-5)`. Is there a way to cirumvent that (i.e. to check for the first value that is "")?

Comment: @idipous, in such situation only with looping...

Comment: If C# is mandatory, then possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/16777960/2707864

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**
Sorry, I initially misunderstood the question, thanks KekuSemau  for clearing that up!

Try:

```
sh.Range["A1", sh.Cells[1,sh.Rows.Count]].End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown).Value;
```

Also, if you know there will be no empty cells in the column you could use CountA:

```
var usedRows = xlApp.WorksheetFunction.CountA(xlWorkSheet.Columns[1]);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16754327/calling-cells-end-in-excel)

Comment: Sorry for downvote, but this is really counterproductive. The OP already uses `Range.End` function which is the programmatic equivalent of pressing ALT-Cursorkeys. No need to tamper with sending keys and looking where `Selection` walks off to.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant CTRL-Arrow.

Comment: The problem is that I am not in A1 but A6 always since that's where the column starts with the previous 5 cells being of no interest to me at that particular moment. could I use something like `sheet.get_Range("A6",????).End;` ?