# Get the last data filled excel row number in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have been trying to get the row number effectively. But it fails where data was cleared and cells were not explicitly deleted.

I guess it is because of the "Used Range".

What I did is using EPPLUS

```
using (var excel = new ExcelPackage(hpf.InputStream))
{
    var ws = excel.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];

    if(ws.Dimension.End.Row > 2003)
    {
        var result = new JsonResult();
        result.Data = "FileLimitExceeded" ;
```

But it gives me incorrect data. How to get the last count effectively.

I found like

```
var Lastrow =  Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row;
```

But the namespaces I could not comprehend. Could anyone help me with a complete and correct answer ?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674573/programmatically-getting-the-last-filled-excel-row-using-c-sharp

Comment: @sowjanyaattaluri That's the point . Even the accepted answer there suffers from Used Range Contraction Issue I guess.

Comment: What does Json have to do with Excel or EPPlus? Where is the range you use? Because the code you posted doesn't try to access any cell

Answer (score 0):

I have come to this senario few days before, so what i did i read the data and put in data table, and then filter the data to show records when data  is not null.
You can go for the same approach.

Comment: That should be a comment, not an answer. Besides, if you can read the data as a DataTable, you already know the valid data range

Comment: Tha data which i read contains the blank rows, so it is is good to eliminate the duplicate rows which are not having data. Which completely makes sense.

Comment: Not quite. If you specify a range, Excel will return cells whether they have data or not. You *don't* need to load this range into a DataTable to find the rows that actually contain data. A LINQ query over the cells will do the same job. The easiest option though would be to create named ranges/tables when generating the file, then access them by name

Comment: Hi , the approach for finding the data accurately is described  in the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27108153/excel-with-qt-find-number-last-filled-row?rq=1 . Please visit and i think it will help out.

Comment: I'm not the OP. I'm commenting that this approach is no better that looking over all the cells, and just not needed. You *can* just perform a `where` LINQ query over a range of cells. And the best option of all, use a named range so you don't need to search for the limits