# Get row count (from specific row) in specific column Excel Interop C#

Tags: c#, excel, interop, vsto, excel-interop

I want to be able to get the number of used rows in column from a specific row (e.g, A2 to last row used in column A).

I tried the following code but was unable to get the desired result (i.e, should be getting 4 but got 5 rows)

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace excel_interop_practice
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\\book1.xlsx");

        Excel.Range xlTestRange;
        Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
        xlTestRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

        int row_used = xlTestRange.Cells[2, 1].End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown).Row;
        Console.WriteLine(row_used);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code opens an excel workbook, gets a range from used range. Then sets an `int` named `row_used` to identify the last used row in row 2 col 1 with:

```
int row_used = xlTestRange.Cells[2, 1].End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown).Row;
```

Then you output the `row_used`.

Running some tests show that if you change the row value, it doesn’t change the value returned. I have a feeling you may have to simply count from the currently selected cell on down until you reach an empty cell in that column.

I don’t understand your comment: *I want to be able to get the number of used rows in column from a specific row (e.g, A2 to last row used in column A).* When you open the document as you are in your code, the currently selected cell will be where ever the selected cell was when it was last saved/closed. So I am guessing this is for a plug-in (VSTO) to Excel and not necessarily intended to be interactive with the user in your C# code. Again I think you may have to count them yourself unless there is another Excel function that will do this.

One solution from @Seth Moore at [Get Last non Empty Cell of Excel Column Programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192167/get-last-non-empty-cell-of-excel-column-programatically)

```
var row_Used = excelApp.WorksheetFunction.CountA(xlWorksheet.Columns[4]);
```

is simply counting all the non-empty cells in the column. It works however as in your code there are some drawbacks you may encounter. A possible problematic scenario is described using the picture below.

[image]

you do not say how you would address issues when Used Range returns something like shown. What would you expect to get in column “C”? Currently both code samples are the same for the first two columns, however in Column “C” your code returns 4 for that column as the first non-empty cell starts at row 4 from the top. The second code results will be 8 using the `CountA`. Column “D” your code returns 2 as expected and 7 for the second. I am not sure how you would want to deal with these situations. Hope this helps.

Comment: How to get the maximum row count from a specific column? For example 12 for the 'B' & 'C' Columns and 9 for 'D' column..?

Comment: @JayNaz… To get the row count of a particular column, as is noted above, you will have to start at the last row returned from used range, and then check each cell in the column you are looking for. Start at the last row from used range, loop up until you find a cell in that column that is not empty. You could use `CountA` also for a particular column; however, this will NOT count empty cells. Therefore using CountA to find the last row with data will not work if there are empty cells in the column sandwiched between the first cell with data and the last cell with data.